# How to resolve response code

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have a certain lotus notes java agent that tests URLs stored from the documents in a view.

However it would seem that the agent detects the certain URL to be valid (response code of 200) even though if you load it manually through a browser you'll see that it displays a message that "the document does not exist" so in a sense it should have a response code of 404.

So I am left assume that the the URL is being redirected to a fake or non-404 page which kinda screws up the process making the agent believe that the URL is still valid.

Is there any ways to resolve this on my side?

I was thinking of that if it detects that particular URL pattern it will try to read the content and checks the html value from a div with a unique id attribute. Would that be possible?

Comment: what is the actual response code for this (I usually use any online response code check tool)?  if it redirects, the response code should be 301 or 302.  If it is returning 200 with custom error message, I don't think there is a generic way to find this pattern unless the URL belongs to your web application.

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. It's returning a response code of 200 with a custom error message. The URL belongs to another web application. All of which, even the database I'm working on, are within the intranet only.

Comment: Is the URL referring to a Domino HTTP server?

Comment: How is the custom error page implemented? At least `$$ReturnGeneralError` returns the original error code. Here are some possibilities how it could be implemented: http://dpastov.blogspot.fi/2012/01/error-pages-in-domino.html